# Bash how to find files with the same content in directories

Tags: bash, diff

How to use the `diff` command in a script to display all the files with the same content in directories?
Maybe I should give more details.

the script should find the same files in the specified
directory and subdirectories and displays them in the terminal sorted in
descending order of the file sizes.

Comment: Show us what you have tried, please.

Comment: I tried to get such a command `diff -s  -r Desktop/ Desktop/`, but nothing out of it.
I do not know how to write the script.
Maybe use a different command?

Comment: `diff -r` recursively compares directories. From your question, it seems like you want to pairwise compare files in some directory and return the pairs that are equal (or the sets that are equal), is that correct?

Comment: I want to display these files that have the same content. I sort the size. At the beginning will see duplicate files that take up the most disk space, then the rest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`diff` does not do this; you need to compare each file to each, in general which is not what `diff` is meant to do.

I propose to use `find` to print a list of all files in the tree in question and sort them by their size.  Only if two files are of the same size, comparing their contents makes sense.  And unless you have a huge amount of files of exactly equal size, this will speed up the process dramatically:

```
find . -type f -printf "%s %p\n" | sort -n | {
  oldSize=none
  while read size path
  do
    if [ "$oldSize" = "$size" ]
    then
      cmp -s "$oldPath" "$path" && echo "$oldPath equals $path"
    fi
    oldPath=$path
    oldSize=$size
  done
}
```

Theoretically this script could fail to find doubles, namely if there are several files of the same size and just some of them truly equal contents.  If they are ordered as A B A by the sort (depending on their path name of course), A and A are never compared so they will go unnoticed.

Comment: to get the A B A problem fixed, you need to use a nested loop. Assuming you are currently at index `n`, you need to compare this file with all the files from here on that still have the same size as this index and match this file with all of them. Then, increase index and go forward. It would make sense to store the file names in an array so you can move back and forth between them. Also, the equality results could be stored in an array (indexed by `n`) so the output could print the whole "set of equal files" instead of printing them pairwise. Although these are all just details.

Comment: Yeah, probably, for instance with a tree full of JPGs, this won't occur anyway, so I figure it is enough to stay aware of this problem.  Actually, I would rather solve it by using a hash of the contents (e. g. md5sum) and sort after that.  Unless you hit a hash collision (extremely unlikely) this should fix the issue for good without introducing a n × n comparison for each file in a group of n equally sized files.

Comment: you're right, using hash is quite good. Anyway, it depends on the file type, but with text files (which OP's use of `diff` suggests), it's very unlikely that two files have the same size but are different, so the time complexity would be `O(n*k)` where `k` is very small w.r.t `n`. This would also be true with `.jpg` files, but probably very wrong with `.bmp` files. Anyway, just wanted to mention those peculiarities for completeness.